# Why is my favicon not looking correct on my first visit?

Tags: favicon

So this is a very odd issue. My favicon is currently working fine on every page BUT the first visit to my website.

[First visit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onH09.png)

[After navigating through site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVC2h.png)

WEBSITE:
http://the-sound-samurai.com/

Everything coding wise seems fine, and I thought it was just a simple "refresh" issue, but no matter what browser or computer, it's the same issue. Only when the site has been visited enough and saved in the history of the browser does it retain the info of the favicon.

Is there a way to fix this or is it not fixable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As i can see you have **two favicon** icons declared.
First one is the default **hostgator** icon remove this one. and you will be shown your own icons.

Comment: There are those moment when you're trying to find something and a friend points out it's in your hand? Or looking for glasses when they're on your face? I feel like that right now. I never noticed I doubled up that. Got rid of it and it works just fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. Clear the browser cache and try again.